# React to Error in Technical Profile

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We have a working user journey scenario (roundtrip), where user signs up/signs in, gets objectId, and at the end, we call a REST service sending the objectId to receive a custom attribute (uniqueidentifier from an on-premise service) to add it as a custom attribute (extension) in Azure AD.

As said this works fairly well, but we would like to react to errors, when the REST service calls fails (e.g. server is down). Now the user shows up in AD, but it is missing the unique identifier as custom attribute.

Is there a way we can react to errors in the execution of a Technical Profile?
For Example, make another REST call, where we can handle this Error? As per default the user now gets to see a standard error page.

Thx